# Unable to install curl via apt on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, curl, apt, ubuntu-20.04

So I tried installing using apt

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install curl
```

It returns done like this and then nothing happens

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

So when checking

```
curl --version
```

nothing is returned.

Please note: Previously installed with snap but that has some issues because it couldn't install nodejs.
So removed it and trying to install from apt.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to reinstall curl via apt:

```
sudo apt reinstall curl
```